# ¿porque al intentar usar send en c se cierra mi programa?

Tags: c, windows, socket

Estoy haciendo un programa servidor que usa sockets y threads y que intenta unir dos conexiones para que dos clientes puedan pasarse un archivo del uno al otro.

Para saber que dos conexiones tiene que emparejar lo que hace es que cada conexion manda un numero y si su pareja ha llegado y tiene el mismo numero los empareja y sino lo mete en un array.Hay dos arrays uno de los que reciben el archivo y otro de los que lo envian.

No se si es la mejor manera de hacerlo pero para que los programas vayan coordinados de vez en cuando el servidor manda a los dos una señal q ellos reciven con recv y al intentar mandar una de esas señales el programa se traba y se cierra (Se traba en el último trozo de codigo que he puesto y he indicado en que linea).

Este es el codigo:

-las estructuras:

```
struct cliente
{
    SOCKET conexion;
    struct sockaddr_in datos;
};

struct archivos_IO
{
    struct cliente sujeto;
    long unificacion;
    short int tipo;
};
```

Las variables globales:

```
int guia_archivos1; //El numero de elementos que hay almacenados en el array 1.
int guia_archivos2;
int general_archivo1; //El numero total de elementos que puede haber en el array 1.
int general_archivo2;
struct archivos_IO *lista1; //Los arrays con las conexiones que se han hecho.
struct archivos_IO *lista2;
```

El main que recibe las conexiones:

```
SOCKET sok,doble;
struct sockaddr_in cliente_numeros;
char recepcion[4];

//Doy un valor inicial a las variables globales.
guia_archivos1=0;
guia_archivos2=0;
lista1= (struct archivos_IO*) malloc(sizeof(struct archivos_IO)*50);
lista2= (struct archivos_IO*) malloc(sizeof(struct archivos_IO)*50);
general_archivo1=50;
general_archivo2=50;

//no he puesto lo de antes para ahorrar espacio pero esta parte es la que clasifica las conexiones.
while((doble=accept(sok,(struct sockaddr*)&cliente_numeros,0))!=INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        pthread_t hilo;
        recv(doble,recepcion,sizeof(recepcion),0);

        if(0==strcmp("2",recepcion))
        {
        struct archivos_IO sujeto;
        struct cliente intermediario;
        intermediario.conexion=doble;
        intermediario.datos=cliente_numeros;

        sujeto.sujeto=intermediario;
        sujeto.tipo=2;

        pthread_create(&hilo,NULL,&organizar_archivo,&sujeto);

        }
        else if(0==strcmp("3",recepcion))
        {
        struct archivos_IO sujeto;
        struct cliente intermediario;
        intermediario.conexion=doble;
        intermediario.datos=cliente_numeros;

        sujeto.sujeto=intermediario;
        sujeto.tipo=1;

        pthread_create(&hilo,NULL,&organizar_archivo,&sujeto);
        }
```

La funcion que las organiza:

```
void* organizar_archivo(struct archivos_IO *sujeto)
{
    int i,bandera=0;
    char recepcion[30];
    struct archivos_IO enlace[2];

    send(sujeto->sujeto.conexion,"a",sizeof("a"),0);
    recv(sujeto->sujeto.conexion,recepcion,sizeof(recepcion),0);
    sujeto->unificacion=atoi(recepcion);

    if(sujeto->tipo==1)
    {
        pthread_t hilo;
        for(i=0;i<guia_archivos1;i++)
        {

         if(lista1[i].unificacion==sujeto->unificacion)
         {
            enlace[0]=lista1[i];
            enlace[1]=*sujeto;
            eliminar_elemento(i,1);
            bandera=1;
            pthread_create(&hilo,NULL,&inte_arch,&enlace);
            break;
         }
        }
        if(bandera==0)
        {
            if(guia_archivos2<=general_archivo2)
            {
                //printf("pasa por aqui\n");
                lista2[guia_archivos2]=*sujeto;
                guia_archivos2++;
            }
            else
            {
                lista2=(struct archivos_IO*)realloc(lista2,sizeof(struct archivos_IO)*(general_archivo2+1));
                general_archivo2++;
                lista2[guia_archivos2]=*sujeto;
                guia_archivos2++;
            }
        }

    }

    if(sujeto->tipo==2)
    {

        pthread_t hilo;
        for(i=0;i<guia_archivos2;i++)
        {

         if(lista2[i].unificacion==sujeto->unificacion)
         {
            enlace[1]=lista2[i];
            enlace[0]=*sujeto;
            eliminar_elemento(i,2);
            bandera=1;
            pthread_create(&hilo,NULL,&inte_arch,&enlace);
            break;
         }
        }
        if(bandera==0)
        {
            if(guia_archivos1<=general_archivo1)
            {
                //printf("pasa por aqui\n");
                lista1[guia_archivos1]=*sujeto;
                guia_archivos1++;
            }
            else
            {
                lista1=(struct archivos_IO*)realloc(lista1,sizeof(struct archivos_IO)*(general_archivo1+1));
                general_archivo1++;
                lista1[guia_archivos1]=*sujeto;
                guia_archivos1++;
            }
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

La funcion que intercambia:

(Esta no está acabada pero se traba al intentar mandar la a al sujeto 0 aunque al sujeto 1 se la manda bien)

```
void *inte_arch(struct archivos_IO sujetos[2])
{
    send(sujetos[1].sujeto.conexion,"a",strlen("a"),0); 
    send(sujetos[0].sujeto.conexion,"a",strlen("a"),0); //<---- apartir de aqui el programa se cierra.

    system("pause");
}
```

Ya se que el programa es muy mejorable pero me ayudariais mucho diciendome porque en ese punto en especial no funciona. Todo lo demás tira mas o menos .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema creo que era que en el hilo que organiza creaba un `struct archivos_IO [2]` y pasaba la dirección de memoria a otro hilo y al acabar el hilo que organizaba se borraba la variable o algo así y por eso no funcionaba. Con poner `ptread_join(hilo,NULL);` al final de la función que empareja las conexiones ya funciona todo bien.

Comment: No está mal que respondas a tu propia pregunta, al contrario. Cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo, recuerda [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.